# Getting a dictionary from web-scrapping data sets

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, code-formatting

```
table = soup.find('table')

list_of_states = table.find_all('tr')

for state in list_of_states:
    state_name = state.find('td')
    if state_name is None:
        continue
    hours = state.find_all('td')[1].text

    comparison_state = str(state_name.text.strip().lower())
    sunlight = float(hours.split()[0])

dict = {comparison_state : 1, sunlight : 2}
```

Alright, I am trying to have the state_name and hours associated, like first state_name = first hours...etc. As you can see, the comparison_state is the string of state names, but if you print that it prints all of them, not just one; same thing with the sunlight. The for loop finds the state names and the hours associated already, but how do I put that into a dictionary or array of dictionaries, that I can then use with user input. For example, if the user entered "Washington", they got the hours associated with that state.

Comment: this would be much easier if you would share the link or html you're working with

Answer (score 0):

> comparison_state is the string of state names, but if you print that it prints all of them, not just one; same thing with the sunlight

Is there one single cell with all the state names and another single cell with all the sunlight hours? Because otherwise that shouldn't be happening with the current code....(I'd really like to see the html you're working with - I can't be sure of anything below otherwise.)

---

> but how do I put that into a dictionary or array of dictionaries

You could initiate the dictionary **before** the for-loop with `sunlightHrs_byState = {}` and then update the dictionary **inside** the loop by adding at the end: `sunlightHrs_byState[comparison_state] = sunlight`; but I think it would be much simpler if you replaced the loop entirely with [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and a [selector](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) [`tr:has(td~td)`] that only targets rows [`tr` tags] with at least 2 cells [`td` tags]:

```py
table = soup.find('table')
sunlightHrs_byState = dict([(
    str(r.find('td').text.strip().lower()), # state name
    float(r.select_one('td ~ td').text.split()[0]) # sunlight
) for r in table.select('tr:has(td~td)')])
```

That should create a dictionary which has the state names (or whatever is in the first column) as keys paired up with the corresponding sunlight hours (or whatever is in the second column) as values - from every row in the table that has two (or more) columns.

---

---

I can't test on *your* html since you've not shared it, but the code below is tailored for [this table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L9Jhl.png) on [FootprintHero](https://footprinthero.com/peak-sun-hours-calculator#peak-sun-hours-map), which looks similar how I think yours probably is:

```py
sunlightHrs_byState = dict([(
    r.find('td').get_text(strip=True), # state name
    (sum(
        float(a.strip()) for a in r.select_one('td ~ td').text.split('-')
    )/len(r.select_one('td ~ td').text.split('-'))) # averages sunlight hours
) for r in soup.select('table#tablepress-4 tr:has(td~td)')])
print(sunlightHrs_byState)
```

and that prints

```py
{'Alabama': 4.7, 'Alaska': 2.5, 'Arizona': 5.5, 'Arkansas': 4.550000000000001, 'California': 5.05, 'Colorado': 4.800000000000001, 'Connecticut': 4.0, 'Delaware': 4.199999999999999, 'Florida': 5.1, 'Georgia': 4.65, 'Hawaii': 5.05, 'Idaho': 4.1, 'Illinois': 4.15, 'Indiana': 4.1, 'Iowa': 4.1, 'Kansas': 4.699999999999999, 'Kentucky': 4.2, 'Louisiana': 4.85, 'Maine': 3.65, 'Maryland': 4.1, 'Massachusetts': 3.9, 'Michigan': 3.7, 'Minnesota': 3.75, 'Mississippi': 4.7, 'Missouri': 4.35, 'Montana': 3.9000000000000004, 'Nebraska': 4.4, 'Nevada': 5.199999999999999, 'New Hampshire': 3.65, 'New Jersey': 4.1, 'New Mexico': 5.5, 'New York': 3.8, 'North Carolina': 4.45, 'North Dakota': 3.9, 'Ohio': 3.9, 'Oklahoma': 4.9, 'Oregon': 4.05, 'Pennsylvania': 3.8499999999999996, 'Puerto Rico': 5.25, 'Rhode Island': 4.0, 'South Carolina': 4.7, 'South Dakota': 4.2, 'Tennessee': 4.3, 'Texas': 5.25, 'Utah': 4.95, 'Vermont': 3.5999999999999996, 'Virginia': 4.25, 'Washington': 3.6, 'Washington DC': 4.15, 'West Virginia': 4.0, 'Wisconsin': 3.8, 'Wyoming': 4.4}
```

---

BTW, <sub>I'm not entirely sure what you're expecting `dict = {comparison_state : 1, sunlight : 2}` to do, but it's just going to create a dictionary named `dict` with two [values](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/dictionary/values) (`1` and `2`); and also, it's **NOT** a good idea to assign variable names that are already [reserved words](https://flexiple.com/python/python-reserved-words/) or [built-in data types](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_datatypes.asp) (like `dict` is).</sub>